# How to convert N-D slice to indexes in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Given any N-tuple of slices (aka N-D slice) in [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) how to convert it to corresponding indexes of N-D array represented as tuple of 1D arrays (indexes along each axes)? E.g. if we have `np.nd_slice_to_indexes` next code:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3]))
print(np.nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3, 5 : 11 : 2]))
```

should print

```
(array([1, 2]),)
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([5, 7, 9, 5, 7, 9]))
```

It is common for NumPy to represent indexes of N-D array as N-tuple of 1-D arrays of same length (each element of `k-th` array in tuple represents next index along k-th dimension). E.g. `np.nonzero` returns such N-tuple in code

```
print(np.nonzero([[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]])) # Non-zero elements in 2D array.
# (array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Same behavior should be achieved like in Pythonic function below, but in a more efficient (performant) way:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64097025var2#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

def nd_slice_to_indexes(nd_slice):
    assert type(nd_slice) in [tuple, slice], type(nd_slice)
    if type(nd_slice) is not tuple:
        nd_slice = (nd_slice,)
    def iter_slices(slices):
        if len(slices) == 0:
            yield ()
        else:
            for i in range(slices[0].start, slices[0].stop, slices[0].step or 1):
                for r in iter_slices(slices[1:]):
                    yield (i,) + r
    *res, = np.vstack(list(iter_slices(nd_slice))).T
    return tuple(res)

print(nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3]))
print(nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3, 5 : 11 : 2]))
print(nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3, 5 : 11 : 2, 8 : 14 : 3]))
# (array([1, 2]),)
# (array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([5, 7, 9, 5, 7, 9]))
# (array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), array([5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9]), array([ 8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11]))
```

Comment: Look at `np.ogrid` and `np.mgrid`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! Works! Added your suggestion regarding `np.mgrid` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64097626/941531).

Comment: @hpaulj Although looking at code of `np.mgrid` it could be the case that it is not very performant implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097025/how-to-convert-n-d-slice-to-indexes-in-numpy/64097626#comment113345591_64097025) of @hpaulj solved task efficiently using [np.mgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html).

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64097025#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

def nd_slice_to_indexes(nd_slice):
    grid = np.mgrid[{tuple: nd_slice, slice: (nd_slice,)}[type(nd_slice)]]
    return tuple(grid[i].ravel() for i in range(grid.shape[0]))
    
print(nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3]))
print(nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3, 5 : 11 : 2]))
print(nd_slice_to_indexes(np.s_[1 : 3, 5 : 11 : 2, 8 : 14 : 3]))
# (array([1, 2]),)
# (array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([5, 7, 9, 5, 7, 9]))
# (array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), array([5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9]), array([ 8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11,  8, 11]))
```

Comment: Might be not efficient, didn't do timings, not sure if `np.mgrid` is impelemented to be really fast.

Comment: How should this code be adjusted for processing a list of slices, e.g. as returned from scipy.ndimage.find_objects?