# Mixing slices with indexes to mgrid input in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, indices

[np.mgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) accepts tuple of slices, like `np.mgrid[1:3, 4:8]` or `np.mgrid[np.s_[1:3, 4:8]]`.

But is there a way to mix both slices and arrays of indexes in a tuple argument to mgrid? E.g.:

```
extended_mgrid(np.s_[1:3, 4:8] + (np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([7,8])))
```

should give same results as

```
np.mgrid[1:3, 4:8, 1:4, 7:9]
```

But in general an array of indexes inside a tuple may not be representable as a slice.

Solving this task is needed to be able to create N-D tuple of indexes provided a mix of slicing + indexing using `np.mgrid` like in [this my answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64097626/941531).

Comment: Explore `meshgrid`, e.g. `np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,3), [1,2,3], indexing='ij')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task solved with [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099215/mixing-slices-with-indexes-to-mgrid-input-in-numpy?noredirect=1#comment113360743_64099215) of @hpaulj using [np.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVHRSsMwFH3PV1zwYY2Gsa4DZ8G/8C2Uka3ZFm3TmKSwIn57vUm7YYeKmodceu85J@eems4fG531vapNYz3otjYdCAfaEFLKPciTl7qU5aY@WFUmiuYE8Fjp4BFB81q6Y5zc8iROzgdnwgp9kImcOy9Qu7GwYBC@GjNUaUIzpROi2oPvDNIoKAeuUjsJsnJ4XWAU9siToDS8RUAOiWKUhUd1KawV3bnjW1PhWL3zKKpoEVUKhuRSnpQ@4B4z9Tyj416@tTrooOfdS4J7MljQiykVTUXRwRQC@KIg5AaepPOOEDHmEkLhaZ4VZIudqxiD/iZOKRHOyZB8yAuNb@RrK6pEMNii/aFeqX6iM/ql/gTxtyciIuGcpywtGF@yZYGFZ2yFJdwFev7myZGbImf4GWMj0Cj9z6q4AYNVvmaQ5isG9/nDz3lGcAF3MLXDsqmhe7b@raG@/wA)

```
import numpy as np

def extended_mgrid(i):
    res = np.meshgrid(*[(
            np.arange(e.start or 0, e.stop, e.step or 1)
            if type(e) is slice else e
        ) for e in {slice: (i,), np.ndarray: (i,), tuple: i}[type(i)]
    ], indexing = 'ij')
    return np.stack(res, 0) if type(i) is tuple else res[0]

# Tests

a = np.mgrid[1:3]
b = extended_mgrid(np.s_[1:3])
assert np.array_equal(a, b), (a, b)

a = np.mgrid[(np.s_[1:3],)]
b = extended_mgrid((np.s_[1:3],))
assert np.array_equal(a, b), (a, b)

a = np.array([[[1,1],[2,2]],[[3,4],[3,4]]])
b = extended_mgrid((np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])))
assert np.array_equal(a, b), (a, b)

a = np.mgrid[1:3, 4:8, 1:4, 7:9]
b = extended_mgrid(np.s_[1:3, 4:8] + (np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([7,8])))
assert np.array_equal(a, b), (a, b)
```